# Passing parameters from Report Viewer to SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I am trying to pass the loged in username from my dot net application to Report Services. This is my code:

```
           string usern = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
           ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
           ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl =
           new Uri(@"http://myserver/reportServer/");
           ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = @"/path/subpath/reportName";
           ReportParameter[] rp = new ReportParameter[1];
           rp[0] = new ReportParameter("paramTest", usern);
           ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(rp);
           ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

When I run it locally, everything works fine, I can see my username on the parameters textbox. Running it on server, I got "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" instead of my username. 
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: *How* was this code running on the server? As a service? As an ASP.NET app?

Comment: It is an ASP app, the code above is on PageLoad method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment confirms what i suspected - `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` *is* your windows identity on the server - it is the [identity the application pool](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/) is running as.

Here are three links that may help you to get the name of the user of your application if you are using Windows authentication:

- [ASP.NET – Get User Name Under Windows Authentication](http://www.whypad.com/posts/aspnet-get-user-name-under-windows-authentication/628/)
- [Getting windows username using windows authentication](http://forums.asp.net/p/1598421/4059545.aspx)
- [How to Get Window NT Logged User Name Using ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/How_to_NT_User_Name.aspx)

Comment: Ok, it's working now. All of the methods worked, the important thing to do was to change the anonymous access to windows authentication. I just hope this change will not affect he rest of my application. Thanks, I really appreciate your help

Comment: @Adolfo, cool, if it worked then don't forget to mark it as the answer (click the check mark to the left of the answer).